# zip extraction in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I want to implement a functionality such that a zip file is uploaded to a document library. I have created an event receiver in which i want to extract zip file. I tried using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll but i got an error as strong name was not assigned to that dll.

So i followed these steps:

1: Dis-assemble the assembly (ildasm)
2: Created strong name(sn -k)
3: Re-Assemble using your strong-name key (ilasm)

and created ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll with strong name and added its reference.The code throws an exception as: "Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.85.5.452, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b18e1de4cba0e84f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

So is there any other way to extract zip file??

Comment: Since ICSharpCode #ziplib  is open source, why not just download and recompile it's source code? http://icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just try to put dll in your virtual directory folder(bin) and remove from GAC.

I had certain issue when I was using ZedGraph. I tried to put ZedGraph dll in GAC and added reference for this dll inside my project. I was also getting same error. Then I just remove ZedGraph.dll file from GAC and put simply inside my virtual directory bin folder.

Comment: The bigger question is how it got into the GAC without a strong name.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the zip file with the following steps (I used Sharepoint 2016):

In the Sharepoint Files view choose "Sync" to sync the content to your local drive.
Open Windows Explorer, locate the file/folder and unzip it.